# androidx gridlayout columns not stretching to width

Tags: android, android-studio, grid-layout

I want to implement a grid layout of 2 columns and 4 rows but the columns are not stretching any way to the width of gridlayout.

I tried columnweight to the children of gridlayout but its not working.

The sdk version is causing problem ?,
i tried this code with min sdk 16, and it was working, when i changed the sdk version it is showing the following output.

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

The code i use is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgapps">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="50px"
    android:paddingRight="50px">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/person" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDashboard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtDashboard"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:text="Sub Title Here"
            android:textColor="#52baff"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="ChatBot"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 2"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 3"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i4" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 4"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 5"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i6" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 6"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/good_quality" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 7"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok_hand" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 8"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

The Gradle is as follow

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hgs_bot"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation project(path: ':mysql-connector-java-5.1.49')
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `android:layout_columnWeight="1"` to all of your childerns inside GridLayout

```
    <GridLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="ChatBot"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 2"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 3"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i4" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 4"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/intent5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 5"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i6" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 6"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/good_quality" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 7"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok_hand" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Intent 8"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

 </GridLayout>
```